# Database is creating multiple rows of the object

Tags: java, database, hibernate, dropwizard, compareto

I understand that a compareTo method is required for the DB to understand that these are same objects, so I wrote a compare to methd for the following object

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "networkServiceConfig")
public class NetworkServiceConfig implements Serializable{

    String endpoint;
    String url;
    String host;
    int port;
    String networkServiceName;
    String uuid;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="networkServiceConfig")
    Service service;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonProperty
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;

    public NetworkServiceConfig() {

    }

    public NetworkServiceConfig(String endpoint, String url, String host, int port, String networkServiceName) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    this.url = url;
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.networkServiceName = networkServiceName;
    }



    public String getEndpoint() {
    return this.endpoint;
    }

    public void setEndpoint(String endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
    return this.url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
    }

    public String getHost() {
    return this.host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
    return this.port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    }

    public void setNetworkServiceName(String name) { 
    this.networkServiceName = name;

    }

    public String getNetworkServiceName() {
    return this.networkServiceName;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
    return this.uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    /**
     * Implement comparable to compare two NetworkServiceConfig objects for equality
     */
    public int compareTo(NetworkServiceConfig o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (this.networkServiceName.equals(o.networkServiceName)) {
        return 0;
    }

    int value = (int) (this.id - o.id);

    if (value == 0) {
        return this.networkServiceName.compareTo(o.networkServiceName);
    }

    return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    NetworkServiceConfig o = (NetworkServiceConfig) obj;
    return this.networkServiceName.equals(o.networkServiceName);
    }




}
```

The network service name is unique for each object. But I see 20 rows created each time when I save this object over various calls to save . Note that thus us a property on a differnet object 
and here is the relation

The Service object :

```
 @OneToOne (cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="networkServiceConfig_id")
    @JsonProperty
    NetworkServiceConfig networkServiceConfig;
```

Also I dont see a networkServiceConfig_id column in the table

Comment: You can either make `networkServiceName` the primary key or add a unique constraint to the table and see which part of your code is trying to store the same service name twice.

Comment: how do I add a unique constraint? isn't the id unique as declared?

Comment: You should delete `id` at all. And make `networkServiceName` as a primary key.

Comment: Thanks going to try that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to check `networkServiceConfig` table for `networkServiceName` duplicates before save and update of `NetworkServiceConfig` and return 422 HTTP status, if `networkServiceName` already exists. It is a bit tricky to do such check for update.

Except that you should add a protection at the database level too, as @xiaofeng.li suggested. You can add a unique constraint for `networkServiceName` or make that field as a primary key.

If you are using `NetworkServiceConfig` as a reference table you should remove  `cascade= CascadeType.ALL`. Also you should use `@ManyToOne` and remove a `Service` association from `NetworkServiceConfig`, if more than one `Service` can have the same `NetworkServiceConfig`

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="networkServiceConfig_id")
 @JsonProperty
 NetworkServiceConfig networkServiceConfig;
```

Comment: So the save is on the service table , and network serviceConfig is a referenced table , does that change anything

Comment: @user_mda You are welcome. Thank you for up vote. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little bit confused, the compare to or comparable implementations for Java, are used for sorting objects when you use Collections Framework, but it is not directly related to the database implementations for Hibernate or JPA

Comment: thanks , how do i make sure a database row is unique

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: It depends on the implementation you are using for ORM, check the annotations available for performing uniqueness of a field.